# How to delete subbuckets for a specific date from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wildcard, glob

I have an `S3` path as below:

```
s3://edl/raw-v2/LOS5DB/
```

Under which there are multiple tables like below:
[image: Path]

Now, consider this path:

```
s3://edl/raw-v2/LOS5DB/LOS5/ADDRESS_DETAILS/
```

This table has parquet data as shown below:

```
edl_load_ts=2020-11-10/ 
edl_load_ts=2020-11-19/  
edl_load_ts=2020-12-10/  
edl_load_ts=2020-12-11/
```

Now I want to delete the data through the `EC2` instance that will delete the data for all the tables that has data `before 20th November`.
For that, I developed a regex pattern as below:

```
aws s3 rm s3://edl/raw-v2/LOS5DB/LOS5/ --recursive --dryrun  --exclude "\*/\*" --include "\*/\*=2020-11-20/
```

But this command deletes all the data under each table under LOS5. It's not working for less than `20th November`. I want it to delete data for every table for the date passed. I cannot do it manually since there are more than 1000 tables per DB.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `include` and `exclude` options [do not support regex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters). These are glob wildcard patterns.

Comment: Ohh! that's surprising! How can I do it?